# Debian unable to dist-upgrade not working

Tags: debian-jessie

I'm trying to update my osmc installation with apt-get dist-upgrade and I get the following

```
Selecting previously unselected package libmagic1:armhf.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtdb1:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libjbig0:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libuuid1:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'busybox' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unable to open files list file for package `hostname': No such device or address
```

Tried solution proposed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/430682/dpkg-warning-files-list-file-for-package-x-missing) but no luck. I'm basically not able to install anything on the machine - everything fails with the message above. Is there any way to fix such installation or do I have to reinstall?

Comment: Is `\`` a typo in the question or did you by chance use it instead of `'` somehwere in you upgrade commands?

Comment: It was just a typo.